# Do foreign keys have size?

Tags: sql, database, memory-management, database-design

I am calculating a database size and I had one doubt about foreign keys. Do they have size? If they are references, do they occupy two different positions in memory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The columns that make up the foreign key do, of course, have size, but they would occupy the same amount of space whether or not they are participating in any foreign key relationship.

Most database products require that the target column(s) of a foreign key reference by indexed - but, again, such an index can exist even in the absence of a foreign key relationship.

Thirdly, the foreign key will require a small (fixed) amount of *metadata* to record its existence.

Beyond that, there *may* be some database products that do require some additional space to implement *some* foreign key features, such as cascading deletes. Such details would be product specific.

But in general, for plain foreign keys, there should be no additional storage requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Every key entry has a size (<= 900 bytes), this includes foreign keys. So yes, each entry in a table counts as its own entry, instead of like a shortcut to the actual reference.